# Remove index.php from laravel 8 url

Tags: laravel

I moved index.php and .htaccess file from public to root directory of laravel so that i can run the site without serving arisan command, but the problem is that for every request i have to include index.php . I make changes in .htacess file but nothing working. can somebody help me to get rid of this problem.

Comment: what you have tried with `.htaccess` ?

Comment: why would you move those to the root of the site? leave those where they are but configure the server to point the document root / web root to the `public` folder of the project

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>
RewriteEngine On
# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php 
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: # Front-controller
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
</IfModule>

Comment: @lagbox you mean to say i have to make changes in apache ?

Comment: I also use second method that is i rename server.php to index.php and copy htacess file form public to root but this also not working